# Why can't I print a random number from 1 to a variable?

Tags: python, random, input

I was making a python program where you type in an input, and it finds a random number from 1 to that input. It won't work for me for whatever reason.

I tried using something like this

```
import random
a = input('pick a number: ')
print(random.randint(1, a))
input("Press enter to exit")
```

but it won't work for me, because as soon as it starts to print it, cmd prompt just closes.
does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Reading error messages you get is important for debugging, I suggest you run the script from cmd or use an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

`randInt()` takes in two `int` data types, `input()` returns a `String`. So all you need to do is convert `a` into an `int`.

So do this

```py
import random
a = input('pick a number: ')
print(random.randint(1, int(a)))
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting a `TypeError`. As `input` saves the terminal data entered by the user as a `str` (string). You need to cast that string into an integer (`int`) to be recognised as a number by Python

```py
import random

# a is a string here
a = input('pick a number: ')

# a is converted to an int here (if it can be)
a = int(a)

print(random.randint(1, a))
input("Press enter to exit")
```

---

Here's how you can force the user to enter a number:

```py
import random

while True:
    # a is a string here
    a = input('pick a number: ')

    try:
        # Try and convert a to an int
        a = int(a)
        # Exit this loop if you didn't get an error
        break
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("That's not a number!")

print(random.randint(1, a))
input("Press enter to exit")
```

If you have an error converting your input to an `int` in the `try` loop, it will go to the `except` part, and will keep looping until it works correctly

---

Further reading here, for learning sake :)

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 1):

randint does not take a string, but you can use try.
If there is an error with a number, then write a message that int is needed.
Sorry for my English.

```
import random;
try:
    a = int(input("pick a number: "))
    print(random.randint(1, a))
    input("Press enter to exit")
except ValueError:
    print("You need to write a number.")
```